# c# FromBase64String() return exception : the input is not a valid base64 on some IOS device like IPHONE 6s

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a web service, it's return a base64 string to a Xamarin Forms app (Android and IOS) after a treatment.

To decode Base64 I use Convert.FromBase64String() on Xamarin app (.NET Standard 2.0)

On android device there is no problem, the returned string is correctly decoded.

On iOS on my iPhone 5s for testing, no problem but on the device of my coworker (iPhone 6s) the following exception was thrown:

> The input is not a valid base64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character more than two padding characters or an illegal character
>   among the padding character

The returned base 64 string :

> 77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4NCjxEYXRhIFZlcnNpb249IjEiPg0KICA8Q29udHJvbHM+DQogICAgPENvbnRyb2w+DQogICAgICA8SWRGcm9tRGV2aWNlPjI8L0lkRnJvbURldmljZT4NCiAgICAgIDxJZEZyb21EQj4xMDIyMjwvSWRGcm9tREI+DQogICAgICA8UmVzdWx0IC8+DQogICAgICA8UmVzdWx0Q29tZm9ydCAvPg0KICAgICAgPElzQWNjZXB0ZWQ+RmFsc2U8L0lzQWNjZXB0ZWQ+DQogICAgICA8SXNBY2NlcHRlZENvbWZvcnQ+RmFsc2U8L0lzQWNjZXB0ZWRDb21mb3J0Pg0KICAgICAgPEVycm9ycyAvPg0KICAgIDwvQ29udHJvbD4NCiAgPC9Db250cm9scz4NCjwvRGF0YT4=

This is in the correct format but does not work on some iOS devices.

Comment: I tried on the desktop to decode the 64 string and got an error.  Make sure you are receiving the entire string on phones that do not work.  As a quick check compare the length of the received string on good and bad phones.

Comment: The english alphabeth only has 2x26 letters (small and large) and 10 digits, for 62 total. The remaining 2 and the padding character are a mater of choice. I did find one definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table but it is possible not everyone properly followed those. Of course then those should also have issues with Email Attachments and inlined Images in Webpages. So it should not be the issue.

Comment: @jdweng: For me it did work, but the result was really wierd: It was XML!

Comment: What is weird about xml being packed into a base 64 string?  Tried again after the update and now it works.

Comment: For me also it's work on all android device and some ios device :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have found the problem, in my result the balize http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\"> is added in production only on iOS.

I have remove the balize and evrething work fine.

I have noted the comment about the xml to base64...

Thx for your advices.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The above Base64 string [decodes](https://www.base64decode.org/) to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data Version="1">
  <Controls>
    <Control>
      <IdFromDevice>2</IdFromDevice>
      <IdFromDB>10222</IdFromDB>
      <Result />
      <ResultComfort />
      <IsAccepted>False</IsAccepted>
      <IsAcceptedComfort>False</IsAcceptedComfort>
      <Errors />
    </Control>
  </Controls>
</Data>
```

You base64 encoded XML? That seems extremely wrong.

The ideal way to send data is as bytes - when the other side knows your [encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) precisely - or at least have someone elses reliable do the de- and encoding for you. But not all options of data transmission support every possible binary value. Some - like early email and webpages - were limited to a subset of English Alphabet.

That is where Base64 comes in. It helps you encode this binary data into letters you knew the medium could trasport reliably.

Now while the original goal of XML was human redability, as a side effect it also allows the reliable transmission over a "not all bytes allowed" medium. It follows all the character limitations and encoding anotation rules that HTML had developed over the decades, so it works everywhere HTML does.

You:

- Took some binary data
- XML encoded it
- Turned the XML back into binary data
- Base64 encoded the data
- Had the data transmitted over the medium
- And then undid those conversions

That is one Text to byte and byte to Base64 layer of conversion to many. The best advise I can give you, is realizing that you propably got stuck deep in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to go back to the original problem so we can help with that one. This thing has just too many points of failrue that are propably entirely unessesary.